# R - Missing values and logical operations

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean-logic, na

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID    VarA   VarB 
001   5      2
002          4
003   6
004    
005   3      5
```

I want to create a third variable `VarC` with the highest values between `VarA` and `VarB`:

```
ID    VarA   VarB   VarC
001   5      2      5
002          4      4
003   6             6
004                 
005   3      5      5
```

I know that this has to be pretty simple. I tried with the `ifelse` function, but I only obtain that when `VarA` or `VarB` is missing also `VarC` is missing.

How can I solve the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the vectorized `pmax` and setting `na.rm` to TRUE:

```
with(myData,pmax(VarA,VarB,na.rm=TRUE))
1]  5  4  6 NA  5
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [?max](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html) with the argument `na.rm=TRUE`.

```
> myData <- read.table(text="ID    VarA   VarB 
+ 001   5      2
+ 002   NA     4
+ 003   6      NA
+ 004   NA     NA
+ 005   3      5", header=TRUE)
> myData$VarC <- apply(X=myData[,-1], MARGIN=1, FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE)
Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> myData
  ID VarA VarB VarC
1  1    5    2    5
2  2   NA    4    4
3  3    6   NA    6
4  4   NA   NA -Inf
5  5    3    5    5
```

Note that line 4 throws a warning because there are no non-missing data.  You can overwrite the `-Inf` with `NA` if you want.